# SQL Server query with group by is throwing an error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to perform the following query with a computed column and a GROUP BY, but for some reason it isn't working.

```
SELECT Alquileres.Matricula, SUM(CostoTotal) AS TotalRecaudado, 
       Vehiculos.Marca, Vehiculos.Modelo 
FROM Alquileres INNER JOIN Vehiculos ON Alquileres.Matricula = Vehiculos.Matricula 
GROUP BY Alquileres.Matricula
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: the error would be useful...

Comment: take your pick of the numerous questions with the same problem... https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsql-server%5d%20is%20invalid%20in%20the%20select%20list%20because%20it%20is%20not%20contained%20in%20either%20an%20aggregate%20function%20or%20the%20GROUP%20BY%20clause

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your query should be like below

```
SELECT 
    Alquileres.Matricula, 
    SUM(CostoTotal) AS TotalRecaudado, 
    Vehiculos.Marca, 
    Vehiculos.Modelo 
FROM 
    Alquileres INNER JOIN 
    Vehiculos 
    ON Alquileres.Matricula = Vehiculos.Matricula 
    GROUP BY 
    Alquileres.Matricula,
    Vehiculos.Marca, -- add this line
    Vehiculos.Modelo -- and this line to group by
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT Vehiculos.Marca, Vehiculos.Modelo, Alquileres.Matricula, SUM(CostoTotal) AS TotalRecaudado
FROM Alquileres 
INNER JOIN Vehiculos 
ON Alquileres.Matricula = Vehiculos.Matricula 
GROUP BY Alquileres.Matricula,Vehiculos.Marca, Vehiculos.Modelo
```

all fields in a select of a groupy by query should be a fonction or one of the group by field.